# Formatting numbers with same width using f-strings python

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I want to format array of numbers with same width using f-strings. Numbers can be both positive or negative.

Minimum working example

```
import numpy as np  
arr = np.random.rand(10) - 0.5 
for num in arr:
    print(f"{num:0.4f}")
```

The result is

```
0.0647
-0.2608
-0.2724
0.2642
0.0429
0.1461
-0.3285
-0.3914
```

Due to the negative sign, the numbers are not printed off with the same width, which is annoying. How can I get the same width using f-strings?

One way that I can think of is converting number to strings and print string. But is there a better way than that?

```
for num in a: 
    str_ = f"{num:0.4f}" 
    print(f"{str_:>10}")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the *sign* [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) option:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.random.rand(10) - 0.5
>>> for num in arr:
...     print(f'{num: .4f}')  # note the leading space in the format specifier
...
 0.1715
 0.2838
-0.4955
 0.4053
-0.3658
-0.2097
 0.4535
-0.3285
-0.2264
-0.0057
```

To quote the documentation:

> The *sign* option is only valid for number types, and can be one of the
>   following:
>
> ```
> Option    Meaning
> '+'       indicates that a sign should be used for both positive as well as
>           negative numbers.
> '-'       indicates that a sign should be used only for negative numbers (this
>           is the default behavior).
> space     indicates that a leading space should be used on positive numbers,
>           and a minus sign on negative numbers.
> ```

Answer (score 16):

Use a space *before* the format specification:

```
#        v-- here
>>> f"{5: 0.4f}"
' 5.0000'
>>> f"{-5: 0.4f}"
'-5.0000'
```

Or a plus (`+`) sign to force *all* signs to be displayed:

```
>>> f"{5:+0.4f}"
'+5.0000'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 (at least 3.11.2) the format is attained by just adding enough space:

```
from numpy import arange

def f1(x):
     return((x**2)-(4*x)+9)

for i in arange(-1,1,0.1):
    print( print(f"{i:5.2f}\t{f1(i):7.2f}")
```

Being the result:

-1.00     14.00
-0.90     13.41
-0.80     12.84
-0.70     12.29
-0.60     11.76
-0.50     11.25
-0.40     10.76
-0.30     10.29
-0.20      9.84
-0.10      9.41
-0.00      9.00
0.10      8.61
0.20      8.24
0.30      7.89
0.40      7.56
0.50      7.25
0.60      6.96
0.70      6.69
0.80      6.44
0.90      6.21

The first digit before the point defines the spaces, thus 5 would be enough to hold 2 decimals, the minus or a space and the dot. For more decimals you would need to adjust the first number correspondingly.